# Splitting the timestamp from the tweet when using a Twitter Callback

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, line-breaks

I have successfully set up my twitter callback on my webpage and everything is working perfectly.

The only thing I would like to do but cannot seem to figure out how is put a line break (or two) between the content of the tweet and the time stamp. For example:

"Hello this is a tweet. 11mins ago"

"Hello this is a tweet.

11mins ago"

This is the script I am using.

```
<div id="twitter_update_list">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1">
</script>
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different options.
First alternative. See the HTML code generated and try to set a CSS style to the "a" element that halds the time.

Second is to modify the code on http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js to generate a different set of DOM elements. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/6eeBM/1/

I have modified slightly the callback function to add a .

Comment: Thank you, your script works perfectly. I have read through it but can't see a </br> tag anywhere? If i want another line break what part of the code are you changing?

Comment: I used a div instead a br. Check the "<div class="time"><a ....." and try to add a br after the "a" element but before </div>

Comment: Got it! awesome! thanks for your help. Not trying to push my luck but do you have any clue why my first line of the tweet is indented? 

www.nwiretechnologies.com/contact.html

I have looked in all my css and can't see what would be causing it?